# topMenu not displaying as childHtml of custom block

Tags: xml, magento-1.6, topmenu

I have the following xml declaration.

```
        <reference name="header">
        <block type="usability/features" name="usability.features" as="usability_features" template=" client/usability/features.phtml" before="-">                
            <block type="usability/offcanvasmenu" name="usability.offcanvasmenu" as="usability_offcanvasmenu" template="client/usability/offcanvasmenu.phtml" before="-">
                 <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" as="topMenu" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
                    </block>  
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

I have inside features.phtml

```
 <?php $this->getChildHtml('usability_offcanvasmenu');?>
```

This works as expected and offcanvasmenu.phtml contains the following

```
<div>
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch');?>
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu');?>
</div>
```

The above code displays the search bar however does not display the menu. A vague guess makes me think it might be something to do with topMenu being a structural block, still as far as I understand the layout system this should still be rendered.

It is possible that the include is unset somewhere else in the theme, however I think it is more likely I have missed a step due to my gaps in understanding.

Comment: which is the magento version ?

Comment: 1.6.2 is the version I'm working with. However I don't think the xml api changed much since then?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento version >= 1.9, then following code may work in your case.

```
<reference name="header">
    <block type="usability/features" name="usability.features" as="usability_features" template=" client/usability/features.phtml" before="-">        
        <block type="usability/offcanvasmenu" name="usability.offcanvasmenu" as="usability_offcanvasmenu" template="client/usability/offcanvasmenu.phtml" before="-">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

This is because from version 1.9 onwards, Magento uses a special menu renderer block to render topmenu which is `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer`. You can see that, in my code this class is included inside the block `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu`.

Answer (score 0):

hmm maybe try with it:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch');?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu');?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You're correct that the return values of getChildHtml method require to be echoed, unfortunately this was a typo in my question.

Comment: ok :) I notice that you set the same alias for your `core/text_list` block and your `page/html_topmenu` block . Try to remove alias on your `page/html_topmenu`block.
When you make a `die()` in your topmenu.phtml what happens?